# How do I set a maximum loading time for a page in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a website which has multiple images which can take some time to load. To spare the users waiting, I have an option in the preferences that determines the maximum loading time of a page. If it exceeds the time limit, the user will be redirected to a fallback website.

For example, let's say the user set the loading time limit to 5 seconds. After  5 seconds (since page onload), if the `document.readyState` is not "complete," we redirect to the fallback site.

Here's what I've tried (didn't work):

```
setTimeout(check, 1);
function check(){
    console.log("check");
    if(document.readyState!="complete"){
        stop();//Placeholder for redirect
        console.log("stopped");
    }else{
        console.log("Loaded");
    }
}
```

How can this be implemented using JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not seem to work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
let timeout = setTimeout(redirect, 5000);

const redirect = () => {
    // redirect to the fallback
}

// jQuery approach
$(document).ready(() => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});


// pure JS approach
window.onload = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
};
```